# Ubuntu: Unable to start eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I removed java-11 and installed jdk-1.8. Now when I try to start eclipse then its throwing the following error:
[image: Here is screen shot of the error]

Being a beginner I searched and found some solutions but not worked for me

Comment: can anybody please add picture of my question because I have 3 points

Comment: *How* did you remove java-11? Are you on a 32-bit machine?

Comment: @nitind I removed by using this command: `sudo rm -r /usr/lib/jvm/*` then `$sudo apt purge oracle-java11-*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.  I'm going to make some assumptions based on some implications of what you've said here.

I assume that you had Java 11 installed, and you had installed Eclipse, and it was working.

You then, for some reason that I can't understand, decided to uninstall Java 11 and replace it with Java 8.

The error message is because when you had Java 11 installed and you installed Eclipse, Eclipse stored the path to the Java 11 distribution in the "eclipse.ini" file.  Now that Java 11 is gone, it cannot start up.

The easiest way to fix this is to reinstall Java 11, and hopefully it will install into the same location as that error message shows it is looking for it.

Now, to address why you might have thought to replace Java 11 with Java 8.  I'm guessing you're working on an application that requires Java 8 to compile and run.  In this context, it's somewhat understandable that you would have done what you did, but it was the wrong thing to do.

Eclipse can run with one Java version, but build and run applications with a different Java version.  In fact, I think it's generally a good idea to run Eclipse with the newest version of Java it can run (generally about a version short of the latest), but build your applications with the version of Java required for those applications.

So, you should have both Java 11 (or newer) AND Java 8 installed.  Run Eclipse with Java 11, and build and run your applications with Java 8.  In Eclipse, you have to register the Java 8 distribution in "Installed JREs" in Eclipse preferences, and also record that Java distribution in the "JavaSE-1.8" Execution Environment, in the preferences tab right below "Installed JREs".  Set your application to require "JavaSE-1.8".

Comment: I would amend that to suggest running Eclipse with the latest LTS release; usually it won't be explicitly taking advantage of anything in the newer releases, so for a few weeks I wouldn't go out of your way to install anything newer than Java 11 for its sake.

Comment: I certainly agree with the first statement. Everything after that I'm having trouble understanding.